# DrawingManager needs an click before drawing -googlemaps

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps-api-3, keyboard-events

I need to draw rectangles on map when **Ctrl** key is pressed. And remove those rectangles once they are drawn.

I created a sample fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/anusreemn/6fey85dd/2/

But, When I enable **drawingManager** by 
`drawingManager.setDrawingMode("rectangle")`, i need to again click over the map to draw. Which is bad :(

What I expect is to permit drawing on the map only when I have pressed the **Ctrl** key, and continue drawing without having to again click on the map.

Can anyone please help.

Comment: Please note that I need to check if ctrl key is pressed all-the-way while I am drawing. I can't find a way to check that in DrawingManager though.

Comment: I really need an answer for this issue, and if you have any issues with the question I have posted, please raise what your concern is! Please check the fiddle link I have provided.

Comment: Yow wrote "And remove those rectangles once they are drawn." so you want to remove the drqwn rectangle on release of ctrl key right?

Comment: @MayurPatel Yes I want to do that too. I have achieved it. That is not my priority concern. My main concern is that i need to ensure that draw is possible only when ctrl key is pressed.

Comment: You can post your own answer how you have solved it.